# Subtracting preceding cumulative values from current value using SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table of distances:

| loc_id | distance |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1844 |
| 3 | 4781 |
| 4 | 12678 |

and would like to subtract the cumulative sum of the preceding distance rows.

| loc_id | distance | between_dist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1844 | 1844 |
| 3 | 4781 | 2938 |
| 4 | 12678 | 7897 |

Comment: Please create a dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14 with some sample data, and update your post with the url and expected result. You are probably looking for `distance - LAG(distance) over (ORDER BY loc_id) `

Comment: I think there are small errors in your data! Also, why not `0` for between_dist for `loc_id` = 2?

Comment: The distances represent a release from a location.  id =1 is the release location.  The results are from a postgis pgr_withPointsCost operation.  The loc_id = 2 is the distance from the release to that location.

Comment: @Lennart That works and was what I was looking for.

Comment: For the first row, lag will be null, but you can use coalesce to handle that according to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was the answer to my question.  Credit to @Lennart - Slava Ukraini

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE between_dist AS
SELECT *,
table.distance - LAG(table.distance) over (ORDER BY table.id) AS between_dist
FROM table;
```

This will output a table of the distances between each location.